# calculate mean of columns which only include column value larger than zero

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to calculate the mean of all columns but only consider the columns' value larger than zero.

For example

```
df_dict={'A':[0,2,10,0],'B':[10,0,30,40],'C':[0,5,10,10]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
df
A   B   C
0   0   10  0
1   2   0   5
2   10  30  10
3   0   40  10
```

normally, if we just use df.mean(axis=1), it would produce

```
df.mean(axis=1)
0     3.333333
1     2.333333
2    16.666667
3    16.666667
dtype: float64
```

what I wanted is: don't consider any value less than or equal to zero when calculating mean, the result I'd to have is
10/1,(2+5)/2,(10+30+10)/3,(40+10)/2 for each row

How to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First mask the unwanted values. NaNs will be ignored.

With [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df.where(df.gt(0)).mean(axis=1)
```

Or with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df.mask(df.le(0)).mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    10.000000
1     3.500000
2    16.666667
3    25.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much for so quickly response and it works! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which I find easier to read is:

```
df.replace(0, np.nan).mean(axis=1)
```